# How to set a different Tooltip over each Grid Row in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, tooltip, row

I want to display a different tooltip for each Grid row. Each row is also composed of multiple elements: TextBlock, TextBox, and Button. The tooltip is not displayed if I add the tooltip directly on the Grid RowDefinition.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition ToolTip="My Tooltip 1" />
  <RowDefinition ToolTip="My Tooltip 2" />
  <RowDefinition ToolTip="My Tooltip 3" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Each row contains the following elements:

```
<TextBlock
  Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="1"
  Padding="10"
  VerticalAlignment="Center"
  FontFamily="SegoeUI"
  FontSize="16"
  Text="TextBlock" />

<TextBox
  Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="2"
  Width="450"
  Height="30"
  Margin="0,0,20,0"
  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
  FontFamily="SegoeUI"
  FontSize="15"
  Text="TextBox" />

<Button
  Grid.Row="1"
  Grid.Column="3"
  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
  Command="{Binding CompileFlagsAddDataCommand}"
  Style="{StaticResource SettingsButton}">
  <Button.Content>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource AddInputImage}" />
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap all those objects in a grid, you can just set the ToolTip of the grid object. Something like this inside the existing grid with the row definitions you have.

```
<Grid Grid.Row=0 ToolTip="Row 0 Tool Tip">
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
     <Button Grid.Column="2"></Button>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row=1 ToolTip="Row 1 Tool Tip">
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
     <Button Grid.Column="2"></Button>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row=2 ToolTip="Row 2 Tool Tip">
     <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
     <TextBox Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
     <Button Grid.Column="2"></Button>
</Grid>
```

This should display the tooltip (I tried it). But if you do it this way, I think you'll have to copy your column definitions into the grids for each row. If the columns are defined in the outer grid, I don't think the objects can find them.

Comment: I can't be more agree with you. If you just want to add a tooltip you can also use WrapPanel because it is less complex. I'm searching for a way to make the Tooltip property from the Grid RowDefinition to work. For me, it seems like it is a design mistake inside the Grid object if you need to use these types of tricks in order to just display a simple tooltip